# Python code does not work, while counter does not work

Tags: python, class, while-loop, tkinter, counter

I am currently working on a project for class and we have come up with a problem. When we run the code, it usually crashes. I am guessing it runs infinitely. This program is also using Tkinter. Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import *
# import the random module
import random``

# set control variables
guess = 0

counter = 0

number=random.randint(0,100)

themain=number

def myGuess():

    guess = float(enter1.get())
    counter= 10


    while guess != number:
        counter = counter - 1

        if guess == number:
            result = "Congratulations!"
            howmany= "You have ", counter, "Tries to spare"
            label2.config(text=result)
            label3.config(text=howmany)
        elif guess > number:
            result = "To high"
            howmany= "You have ", counter, "Tries left"
            label2.config(text=result)
            label3.config(text=howmany)
        elif guess < number:
            result = "To low"
            howmany= "You have ", counter, "Tries left"
            label2.config(text=result)
            label3.config(text=howmany)





root=tk.Tk()
root.title("Guessing Game")
#-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

label1 = tk.Label(root, text=' Enter value:')

enter1 = tk.Entry(root, bg='red')

btn1 = tk.Button(root, text=' Enter Number', command=myGuess)

label2 = tk.Label(root, text='')

label3 = tk.Label(root, text='')

#-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

enter1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

btn1.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=5)

label2.grid(row=2, column=1)

label3.grid(row=3, column=0)

I hope you guys can help!
```

Comment: you never change the value of `guess` it cannot get out of the loop.

Comment: If Python crashes there is a traceback, Can you show us that traceback?

Comment: your'e trying to call `number` in myGuess function which is locally, if you want to use `number` variable of `random.radint(0,100)` you have to mark `number` as global. write `global number` on top of the script

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you never change the value of `guess`. For crash we need more information like the traceback.

Comment: No error, just crashes, does not respond. But we do not need guess to change, we need counter to change.It will not subtract in the definition.

Answer (score 0):

For the below line, what is enter1 ?

- guess = float(enter1.get())

Answer (score 0):

You should completely remove the while loop. - It makes no sense. 
The code runs "correct"  without it and does what you need.

However you seem to need a check of the number of tries have been reached.